# AngularCompilerPlugin with multipe node_modules folders

Tags: angular, webpack, monorepo, angular-aot

I am working on a monorepository that houses multiple angular (v7) applications.

Angular AOT compilation with webpack gives me trouble.

The top-level structure looks like this:

- application 01

  - node_modules
  - src
- application 02

  - node_modules
  - src
- ...
- **shared**

  - node_modules
  - src

All application can use code from the shared folder. Everything works perfectly until AngularCompilerPlugin's second compilation phase is run.

It throws errors like:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../../Shared/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/index.ngfactory'
```

Components and services from the shared folder seem not to be created and/or included in the compilation.

Has anyone stumbled over a similar issue?

Is it possible to make the AngularCompilerPlugin included factory files from multiple source directories?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

i have only one node_module  folder on project with same structure. I use `nrwl/nx` for more workspaces.

[See it on  github](https://github.com/nrwl/nx)

My structure:

```
apps
  - app1
     - src
  - app2
     - src
libs
  - shared1
     - src
  - shared2
     - src
node_modules
```

Why you need more node_modules?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ErikHer. Maybe the structure you suggested would be better. I will definitely consider it.

However, since everything works fine when compiling the thing without AOT, I would still like to understand how to use AngularCompilerPlugin for my particular setup.